# How to relabel address with it's current value and a label

Tags: prometheus

In a json config file (referred to from `file_sd_configs` ) I have entries such as

```
[
...
    "targets": [ "10.123.456.789"],
    "labels": { "node_exporter_port": "9300" }
  },
...

]
```

In Prometheus configuration I'd like to `relabel_configs` so that the value of `__address__` is the current value of address plus the port. Attempts such as the following do not work:

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [node_exporter_port]
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: __address__
    replacement: [__address__]:${1}
```

EDIT: The following seems to work:

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__, node_exporter_port]
    separator:     ';'
    regex: '(.*);(.*)'
    target_label: __address__
    replacement: ${1}:${2}
```

Is this idiomatic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the separator to colon you can remove the regex and replacement, as the defaults do what you need.

The port label should be prefixed with __ so that it doesn't end up as a target label.

Comment: Cleaned up `relabel_configs` :

`    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__, __node_exporter_port]
        separator:     ':'
        target_label: __address__
`

Answer (score 0):

The following relabeling config appends the port from `node_exporter_port` label to the `__address__` label:

```yaml
- source_labels: [__address__, node_exporter_port]
  target_label: __address__
  separator: ':'
```

It joins the original `__address__` label value and the `node_exporter_port` label value with the given `separator: ':'`.